# WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR on windows 8.1 Update 1, what's the cause?

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I've recently updated to Update 1, from windows 8.1 with all the most recent updates installed already. While I had music playing on foobar2000, and web browsing on chrome I noticed the disk activity light on my desktop was almost non-stop and my system slowed to a crawl. After pressing the power button (to no avail) I eventually had a blue screen with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR, 0x124. A link to the dump file can be found here: [minidump](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lie5d1l61ui7ma1/041614-16046-01.dmp)

**Noteworthy Drivers I can think of that are installed**

- NVidia GeForce 335.23
- Qualcomm Atheros AR938x

Comment: What drivers were loaded when this BSOD happened?  Update your question to include that information.  Did you install all updates before you installed "Update 1" and/or since installing it install all released updates?  I am pretty sure its not possible to install this "Update" without first installing the previous updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an Internal unclassified error with your Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffe0011970a028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000f2000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000100402, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx


FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_genuineintel_processor_mae

===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe0011970a028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cf596a07a4b7b4
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 4/16/2014 15:57:10 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe0011970a0a8
Section       @ ffffe0011970a180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000206a7
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe0011970a0f0
Section       @ ffffe0011970a240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : a7 06 02 00 00 08 10 00 - bf e3 9a 1f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe0011970a240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe0011970a138
Section       @ ffffe0011970a2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Internal unclassified (Proc 0 Bank 4)
  Status      : 0xf200000000100402


BiosVersion = U1j
BiosReleaseDate = 03/06/2013
BaseBoardManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoardProduct = Z68XP-UD3



[CPU Information]
~MHz = REG_DWORD 3293
Component Information = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Configuration Data = REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Identifier = REG_SZ Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
ProcessorNameString = REG_SZ Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz
Update Status = REG_DWORD 6
VendorIdentifier = REG_SZ GenuineIntel
MSR8B = REG_QWORD 2800000000



CPUID:        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz"
MaxSpeed:     3300
CurrentSpeed: 3293
```

Make sure the CPU doesn't overheat. Also look for a BIOS/UEFI update.

Comment: Am running latest UEFI update already: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3892#bios  ambient temperature is low where my desktop is located and my cpu cooler is seated properly with thermal paste applied correctly. I'm also not overclocking. I guess maybe the UEFI is unstable then.

Comment: contact Gigabyte for support. Maybe they can fix it with a new BIOS/UEFI version.